# In a dynamically added input in form, it loses focus when characters are entered in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

I have not found a post which answers issue with dynamic fields which are added based on lets say array length.

```
const [otherSources, setOtherSources] = useState<Source[]>([])
const SourceView = (source: Source & { index: number }) => {
    return <div>
        <div className="field">
            <label className="label">Name</label>
            <div className="control">
                <input className="input" onChange={(event) => {
                    const copyOtherSources = otherSources
                    const sourceElement = copyOtherSources[source.index]
                    sourceElement.name = event.target.value
                    setOtherSources([...copyOtherSources])
                }} value={source.name} />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
            <label className="label">Url</label>
            <div className="control">
                <textarea className="textarea" onChange={(event) => {
                    const copyOtherSources = otherSources
                    const sourceElement = copyOtherSources[source.index]
                    sourceElement.url = event.target.value
                    setOtherSources([...copyOtherSources])
                }} rows={2} value={source.url} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
return (
    <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Other Sources (comma separated)</label>
        {
            (otherSources?.length ?? 0) > 0 &&
            otherSources.map((source, index) => {
                return <SourceView {...source} index={index} key={`field${index}`} />
            })
        }
    </div>
)
```

If I enter any character in any of input then focus moves away. Can someone please highlight what is the issue here?

---

Fix: I was using SourceView as a React component, which was causing it to rerender and the focus to move away. If I directly call SourceView() instead of  focus stays. Other issue is that SourceView was defined inside render method.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fix: I was using SourceView as a React component, which was causing it to rerender and the focus to move away. If I directly call SourceView() instead of  focus stays. Other issue was that SourceView was defined in the render method.

Answer (score 1):

try below solutions.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);


return (
    <div>
      {array.map((value, index) => {
        return <input key={`array${index}`} type="text" />;
      })}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setArray([...array, array.length + 1]);
        }}
      >
        Add more Input fields
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Not working for me, please recheck the updated code once.

Comment: I have also tried adding keys to SourceView and all input elements

Answer (score -1):

There are some syntax errors in your code, but when you solve them it works and focus stay if you type in the input

See below what needs to be corrected

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      {array.map((value, index) => {
// add return before input and curly braces around key
       return <input key={`array${index}`} type="text" />;
      })}
      <button onClick={() => setArray([...array, array.length + 1])}>
        {" "}
        Add more Input fields{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

see codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-keldysh-bn1gbw?file=/src/App.js:23-412

Comment: Not working for me, please recheck the updated code once. Actually in my code I was already returning it

Comment: I have also tried adding keys to SourceView and all input elements

Comment: @TarunChawla It is working but you didn't share the right code. your new code example looks very different than before. You are creating the SourceView component inside the render of another component. This means the state will reset every render.

SourceView should be a separate component that you create outside of the other component.

Comment: I was just trying to share the approach I am using so that I helps other folks to understand the problem, it was not a working code